# is there a way to toggle a class in a list without affecting other toggles

Tags: javascript

i am working on a todo list. That show the title with and arrow. This down arrow(when clicked) is supposed to open only it's own paragraph text but it is affecting other titles and their paragraph.

I have tried to use for each in jquery but it is still doing the same thing

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".arrow").click(function(e) {
        $(".para").slideToggle("slow");
    })
 });
```

i expect each list title arrow when clicked should only show it's paragraph text and not others at the same time.

Comment: Did you expect the `.para` selector to only target a single element? You haven't posted your relevant HTML (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), but a safe assumption is that `$(".para")` matches more than one element. The answer here is to use a more specific selector, which the community can't possibly lead you to without your HTML.

Comment: Show us the relationship between them. It's often a simple traverse, or they can sometimes be indexed

Comment: Can you give us your HTML please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can scope the element being modified to the item that was clicked. To do that, first find the item or container that was clicked and then locate the target within that item. For example, if each item were within an element of the `item` class, you could locate the container and then search within it.

```
$(".arrow").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.item').find(".para").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: The search pattern depends on the exact structure of your page.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did not actually read through what you posted. I just went on to copy the code without actually undestanding what you said. Thanks, you're a genius